# Telegram-desktop can't attach files

Tags: telegram

Telegram-desktop can't attach any file: can't see any file in attach dialog, nor open any drag-n-dropped file.

**Telegram installed correctly, I'm not asking how to install it.**

I installed Telegram Desktop via snap.

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

When I open file browser, it shows empty folders. When I drag files into app window, it shows a popup `can't attach empty file <filename>`.

In `htop`, application `Telegram` has my own user. Everything seems to work correctly except for attachments. Here's what it prints to stdout/stderr in shell:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" (uid=1000 pid=23067 comm=\"Telegram \" label=\"snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties\" member=\"GetAll\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=889 comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
nmReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.663\" (uid=1000 pid=23067 comm=\"Telegram \" label=\"snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" member=\"GetDevices\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=889 comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
"Object path cannot be empty"
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @N0rbert I've installed telegram, it's not a problem to install it, but to let it open files.

Comment: @N0rbert there's nothing in that question/answer that answers my question here.

Comment: Very often Snap'ed applications cause non-predictable problems. Try to install Telegram by different way. I use deb from `ppa:atareao/telegram`. It works without problems.

Comment: @N0rbert mm, ok, will try now. Thanks!